# Não consigo fazer o insert no banco

Tags: php, html

Fiz esse código para registrar um cliente no db de um site.
O código está voltando como se o campo estivesse vazio.

Alguém pode me dizer se fiz algo errado??

PHP
 


`session_start();
include('conect.php');

// RECEBE O SINAL DO BOTAO
if(isset($_POST['btn_cad_cli'])){

    // CHECA SE OS CAMPOS FORAM PREENCHIDO 
    if(empty($_POST['nome_cli']) || empty($_POST['sobnome_cli']) || 
    empty($_POST['email_cad_cli']) || empty($_POST['senha_cad_cli'])) {

        // SE NAO. VOLTA PARA A PAGINA E ENCERRA SESSAO
        Header('Location: ../cadastro_cli.php');
        exit();
    }else{

        // CRIA AS VARIAVEIS
        $nome = htmlentities($_POST['nome_cli']);
        $sobNome = htmlentities($_POST['sobnome_cli']);
        $email = htmlentities($_POST['email_cad_cli']);
        $senha = htmlentities($_POST['senha_cad_cli']);

        // DA UM INSERT NA TABELA
        $mysqli->query("insert into login_cli values('','$nome','$sobNome','$email','$senha')");
        echo $mysqli->error;

        if ($mysqli->num_rows > 0){

            Header("Location:../index.php");
            exit();
        }else{
         Header('Location: ../cadastro_cli.php');
        exit();
        }

    }

}   


?>`

Comment: Bom, o primeiro campo dos `values` da SQL está vazio. Por que?

Comment: É o campo onde vai gerar o ID da tabela. esta como auto_increment

Comment: Não é melhor especificar default no primeiro campo? `"insert into login_cli values(DEFAULT, '$nome', '$sobNome', '$email', '$senha')"`

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão é você usar envio por meio de parâmetros principalmente porque vai sofrer com sqlinjection no modo que está sendo feito, mas, mantendo como você está desejando fazer, tente assim:

```
$mysqli->query("insert into login_cli (nome, sobnome, email, senha) values(".$nome.",".$sobNome.",".$email.",".$senha.")");
```